# How to draw directly to an inactive display?

Tags: windows, graphics, multiple-monitors

I noticed that, when you are changing monitor resolutions in Windows with extra monitors attached, you can select "Show desktop only on [n]" (where n is the number of your various displays).

Is it possible to write a program that will open an extra monitor (not being used by Windows, but plugged into the video card) and write image data to it (directly or through OpenGL or something)? Where would I begin looking to accomplish this?

Comment: Sure you could create transparent windows on each monitor and display whatever you want...

Comment: Sorry, @peterept3, I had meant drawing directly to an inactive display. So essentially taking a monitor that Windows was ignoring and have your application draw to that instead of having to go through the default Windows path of opening a window and drawing to it. I have updated my question to indicate a monitor not being used by Windows.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "not being used by windows" ? Because any monitor plugged in is automatically going to be used by windows - even if it looks black it is part of the desktop area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not appear to be possible to draw directly to a monitor device. It may become possible to some extent with the release of Nvidia and ATI's updated drivers for VR headsets, however it seems that these are only available for Oculus Rift at the moment, with other VR headsets forthcoming.

I haven't found any mention of whether or not they intend to open this feature up to general use with any plug-and-play monitor.